# wpf UserControl get and set values

Tags: c#, wpf, forms

I have a user control

```
<UserControl x:Class="NeocClinic.WPFSystem.Templatas.LoggedAsUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" >
    <StackPanel Name="StackHeader">
        <Grid ShowGridLines="False" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Name="tbLoggedAs" Text="Logged As:" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="0" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="14"/>
            <TextBlock Name="tbLogOut" Text="Log Out"  Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1"  FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="14" Cursor="Hand" MouseDown="tbLogOut_MouseDown"/>


        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

now i wanted to set the tbLoggedAs.Text into whatever the Username of the logger will be.

the problem is, i cant find the user control nor the tbLoggedAs in code, unless i create an instance of this user control, but doing so means it will be a different object than the user control being deployed in the form right?

btw the values that i wanted to set is already done, a retrieval of User object. also, i wanted to get the text of the tbLoggedAs and use it as reference to my CreatedBy field but like I said, I couldnt find it in code, the intellisense is not showing them.

also, is there any way to make the FontSize flexible? i mean whenever i resize my form, the control's size varies but the fontsize stay stagnant.

Comment: How you did you use that `UserControl` in XAML? Another thing: one specific question at a time. [Split your questions to different posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts).

Comment: i just added those other questions since the program didnt allow me to post it because it has more codes than questions X)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use binding here so you can bind textbox to the respective property

example

assuming you have a property called LoggedInUser in your main view model or code behind

```
<TextBlock Name="tbLoggedAs" Text="{Binding LoggedInUser, StringFormat=Logged As: {0}" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="0" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="14"/>
```

note for the binding applied on Text property

so if you have the view model as data context then it will work otherwise you can assign the data context in the code behind which contains LoggedInUser property

eg.

```
DataContext = this;
```

for font size you may have another property in your view model which would be calculate based on the app size and will be binded to font size

eg

```
FontSize="{Binding FontSize}"
```

rest binding framework will handle for you